# Closure in the Discrete Topology

Tags: general-topology, gre-exam

> If $\tau$ is the discrete topology on the real numbers, find the closure of $(a,b)$

Here is the solution from the back of my book:

> Since the discrete topology contains all subsets of $\Bbb{R}$, every subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is both open and closed. Therefore, the closure of $(a,b)$ is $[a,b]$.

Whaaat?! This must be a mistake. Please tell me this is a mistake.

Comment: It is a mistake. Since $(a,b)$ is open and closed, the closure of $(a,b)$ is $(a,b)$ itself.

Comment: OK, I'll tell you. It's a mistake!

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely a mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is wrong. 
Every set in the discrete topology is both open and closed. Closure of a closed set is itself. Hence, the answer should be $(a,b).$

Answer (score 2):

The above comments and answers are absolutely correct.

But we can prove that there is a mistake in your book,by contradiction.

Suppose that $cl(a,b)=[a,b]$ Then $a \in cl(a,b)=[a,b]$ and form definition of closure,we know that a point $x$ is in the closure of a set $A$ in a metric space $X$ if every open ball with center $x$ intersects the set $A$

Now for $A=(a,b)$ we have that the ball  $B(a,\frac{1}{2})=\{a\}$ in a discrete metric space $(\mathbb{R},d_{dis})$ and $\{a\} \cap (a,b)= \emptyset$

We contradict the definition of closure.